# Spring Batch job restart and status tracking

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I use H2 database as the job repository. After application relaunch, I need to continue or restart previously uncompleted Spring Batch Jobs.

Right now I use the following code in order to achieve this:

```
    jobRegistry.register(new ReferenceJobFactory(documetPipelineJob));

    List<String> jobs = jobExplorer.getJobNames();
    for (String job : jobs) {
    Set<JobExecution> runningJobs = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job);

    for (JobExecution runningJob : runningJobs) {
        runningJob.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
        runningJob.setEndTime(new Date());
        jobRepository.update(runningJob);
        jobOperator.restart(runningJob.getId());
        LOGGER.info("Job restarted: " + runningJob);
    }
```

It works fine but has one side effect - it produces the new record in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`  table and assigns it new `executionId` value. But I use `executionId` value in order to track the job status:

```
jobExplorer.getJobExecution(executionId).getStatus()
```

So, I use the following logic - I schedule the job and return the `executionId`. Later, I use this `executionId` in order to track the status of my job. With the restart logic the I have mentioned above - I return the `executionId`, and than restart the application and after the application startup my logic restart the uncompleted jobs and assigns them the new `executionId`. So, in this case, I'm unable to track the status of the new restarted job because I have the old `executionId` only.

How to properly check the job status in this case or how to properly restart the jobs in order to be able to track their status with the old `executionId`?